# How to add some code to the same page the visual editor appears in?

Tags: wordpress

This must be an easy question for those who are not new to Wordpress (I am).

I want to add some HTML (a `<script>` tag, actually) to the page where you edit a post. I do *NOT* want to add HTML code to the post itself, rather I want to add some stuff somewhere in the code *around* the editor.

I think what I need is to hook into some action that fires when the editor page is created, but I'm not sure.

(I am guessing this is probably not a good practice but I'm trying to do a quick and dirty hack to save myself a lot of time in a project that is not going to be reused in the future. I want to use javascript to modify the editor page slightly when the DOM ready event fires.)

Also, can I do it from my theme's `functions.php` file, or does it have to be a plugin?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can't you add it with custom fields?

Comment: I don't see how custom fields would help me add javascript code to an editor page. Custom fields are for adding, well, custom fields to a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple function which you can put in you `functions.php` file and add your script code, and it will only show up on the new/edit post page:

```
add_action('admin_footer','add_my_script');
function add_my_script() {
    global $pagenow;
    if (in_array( $pagenow, array( 'post.php', 'post-new.php' ) )){
        ?>
        <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
            //your script here
        </SCRIPT>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do anything that a plugin can do from the functions.php file in your theme, it just won't be portable.  You will need to find the right action hook, they are listed here and then add your action.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

The WordPress admin uses jQuery, so you should be able to include a jQuery function by registering the script from functions.php and then apply whatever you need from there.

You might be better asking this question on the WordPress forum.

/peter

Comment: Thanks. I had already seen the Action Reference page, but unfortunately the documentation is very poor and it's not obvious what each action corresponds to. It turns out `admin_footer` was what I wanted.